# React project showing babel plugin errors on Codeship

Tags: babeljs, codeship, react-starter-kit

Attempting to set up my react starter kit project to have CI on codeship, and the project works fine locally.  I'm getting the following error `ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "syntax-trailing-function-commas" specified..` when I'm attempting to run npm test on codeship.

My test command

`mocha --require babel-register`

How do I need to configure the codeship environment to get this to work?

package.json

```
...

  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
      "transform-async-to-generator",
      "transform-es2015-destructuring",
      "transform-es2015-parameters",
      "transform-es2015-duplicate-keys",
      "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
      "transform-exponentiation-operator",
      "transform-runtime"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "rewire"
        ]
      }
    }
  },

"dependencies": {
    "apollo-client": "^0.5.20",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.18.0",
    "bluebird": "3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "braintree": "^1.46.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "express-graphql": "0.6.1",
    "express-jwt": "5.1.0",
    "fastclick": "1.0.6",
    "fbjs": "0.8.6",
    "front-matter": "2.1.1",
    "graphql": "0.8.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "history": "4.4.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "1.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.1.9",
    "markdown-it": "8.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "1.6.3",
    "normalize.css": "5.0.0",
    "passport": "0.3.2",
    "passport-auth0": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "2.1.1",
    "pretty-error": "2.0.2",
    "query-string": "4.2.3",
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-apollo": "^0.7.1",
    "react-dom": "15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.5",
    "react-stack-grid": "^0.1.1",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^1.1.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.3.2",
    "redux-logger": "2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.4.6",
    "speakingurl": "11.0.0",
    "universal-router": "2.0.0",
    "uploadcare-widget": "^2.10.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-template": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-types": "^6.19.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.10.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gaze": "^1.1.2",
    "git-repository": "^0.1.4",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "pixrem": "^3.0.2",
    "pleeease-filters": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^5.2.5",
    "postcss-calc": "^5.3.1",
    "postcss-color-function": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-media": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-selectors": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "postcss-media-minmax": "^2.1.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^2.3.1",
    "postcss-partial-import": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss-pseudoelements": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-matches": "^2.0.5",
    "postcss-selector-not": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.0",
    "react-deep-force-update": "^2.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.3",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sinon": "^2.0.0-pre.3",
    "stylelint": "^7.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^15.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.13.2",
    "webpack-middleware": "^1.5.1"
  },
```

Comment: You're using `syntax-trailing-function-commas` so you should have a devDependency on `babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas`, same for every plugin in your list.

Comment: how come the project works locally - I didn't install those dependencies globally

Comment: Maybe you installed them and forgot to put it in your package.json but installed it at some point?

Comment: using the boiler plate react-starter-kit so I think it must somehow reference them